# MySQL fulltext selection performance

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I have **1.5M** rows in a table. Following is the table create code:

```
CREATE TABLE `jobs` (
    `id` INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `job_id` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `title` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `company` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `city` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `state` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `job_id` (`job_id`),
    FULLTEXT INDEX `search` (`title`, `company`, `city`, `state`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=MyISAM
```

The query below takes about 0.5 seconds, which is very high.

```
SELECT id, title, company, state, city FROM `jobs` WHERE MATCH (title, company, state, city) AGAINST ('software engineer in san fransisco california')  LIMIT 0,10
```

**How can I decrease execution time and still provide relevance results? Any suggestions?**

So far I tried followings but there is no improvement at all.

-Searching in a single field that contains 4 field of data but it did not matter.

-Using in boolean mode>1 or >2, but then it gives me unrelated results

-Repearing the table, increasing key_buffer_size to 1GB from 16MB, changing table type to Innodb, changing character set to latin1 from utf8.

-Setting ft_max_word_len=1 and ft_stopword_file='' from default values.

-I searched online for many hours but no luck so far.

"Explain select..." output:

```
id;select_type;table;type    ;possible_keys;key   ;key_len;ref;rows;Extra
1 ;SIMPLE     ;jobs ;fulltext;search       ;search;0      ;\N ;1   ;Using where
```

**Edit:** Thank you for your suggestions but there is no imprevement at all.

Comment: Can you add the `explain select ...` output?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Everything in the table is in English language. Should I change utf8_general_ci to something else?

Comment: Check the value of `ft_max_word_len` and `key_buffer_size`. Yes, if it's English only, consider `latin1` character set.

Comment: Thanks, @MarcusAdams. Should i choose latin1_bin or latin1_general_ci or latin1_general_cs? ft_max_word_len is at default, and key_buffer_size=16M. 16M is low but key_cache_hit_percentage is about %99.

Comment: `latin1_general_ci` is the standard collation for `latin1` character set. The ideal `key_buffer_size` fits all MyISAM indexes in memory.

Comment: There is no improvement at all, after changing character set to latin1, key_buffer_size to 1GB from 16M.

Comment: How big (how many rows) in your result set if you don't `LIMIT` it? You may want to pose this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ because it sure smells like a server configuration problem.

Comment: @OllieJones For the given query about 300,000.

Comment: 0.5s to transfert 300k rows: I don't think you can hope for much better.

Comment: @RandomSeed (facepalm) 0.5s for 10 rows not 300k...

Comment: The thing is, the `LIMIT` clause is applied at the very last stage in the processing of the query. (I believe) the 300k rows must still be pulled internally. The LIMIT clause would only reduce the volume of data transfered to the client. To make sure, try to [profile your query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profile.html) with and without the LIMIT clause.

Comment: @RandomSeed I tried it. Without LIMIT "sending data" takes about 2 seconds, and the rest are almost the same.

Comment: Okay, so this must be a configuration issue on the server. I concur with Olli Jones, you may get better responses at dba.stackexchange.

Comment: This might help: https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/07/31/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-part-3/  MyISAM FT-search queries typically are 0.0005 seconds, so, you are right that something is wrong.